# Show that the the multipliction and inverse operations on the quaternion unit sphere are continuous

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, continuity, quaternions

This is a bit of a tricky question, we define the real Quaternions as: $$H=\left\{ a+bi+cj+dk\mid a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}\right\}$$
With the rule that: $$ij=-ji=k\:,\: jk=-kj=i\:,\: ki=-ik=\, j\;,\: i^{2}=j^{2}=k^{2}=-1$$
We expand the multiplication to the rest of the set by linearity and distributivity and it's worth mentioning that the inverse comes out: $$\left(a+bi+ci+jk\right)^{-1}=\frac{a-bi-cj-dk}{a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2}}$$
We also define the conjugate in $H$
  to be $\overline{a+bi+cj+dk}=a-bi-cj-dk$
  and we define a norm on $H$
  by $\left|z\right|=\sqrt{z\cdot\overline{z}}$
  (which is multiplicative and real). Using this norm we can define the unit sphere in $H$
  to be $$S^{3}=\left\{ z\in H\mid\left|z\right|=1\right\}$$
Now I've shown the following two things:

1. There is a ring-isomorphism between $H$
   and the matrix ring $M_{2}\left(\mathbb{C}\right)$.
2. The unit sphere is a multiplicative group.

I need to show that if we identify $H$
  with $\mathbb{R}^{4}$
  by $a+bi+cj+dk\mapsto\left(a,b,c,d\right)$
  and give $H$
  the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$
  then the multiplication mapping $S^{3}\times S^{3}\to S^{3}$
  defined by $\left(z_{1},z_{2}\right)\mapsto z_{1}\cdot z_{2}$
  and the inverse mapping $S^{3}\to S^{3}$
  defined by $z\mapsto z^{-1}$
  are continuous.

I've tried doing this directly but it comes out being quite a pain so I assume there might be some nifty trick that would simplify the whole thing.

Comment: If it makes you happy, there is a mapping to 4 by 4 real matrices that works; $1$ becomes $I,$ and $i,j,k$ become matrices with only four nonzero entries each. Matrix multiplication is then continuous, and inverse of a matrix with determinant $1$ has polynomial entries from the original (just the conjugate, as you note) and continuous again.

Comment: Hmm ye I suppose that would work better as it solves it without dealing at all with the topology on the sphere itself. Thanks

Comment: Multiplication $\mathbb{H}\times\mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{H}$ produces coordinates that are polynomials in the factors' coordinates. Hence it is continuous. The restriction to $S^3\times S^3 \to S^3$ is hence also continuous. The conjugation is continuous on $\mathbb{H}$. On $S^3$, the inversion $z\mapsto z^{-1}$ is the restriction of conjugation, hence continuous.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the multiplication mapping on $H\times H\simeq\mathbb R^4\times \mathbb R^4$ with values in $H\simeq \mathbb R^4$, each of its components is a simple polynomial function, hence they're continuous and so is the multiplication.

Hence the multiplication is continuous when restricted to $S^3\times S^3$.

For the inverse, you gave yourself the expression of the inverse of a quaternion and it's not hard to see that the inverse mapping is just the conjugation of quaternions on $S^3$ (clearly another continuous function).